# How to use MVC and include files in my node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

I Have a Node app, I have three files and am trying to structure my node in a MVC pattern.

I want a way to put all my requires and variables in my **server.js** all the routes in my **routes.js**  and my functions in my **controller.js**.

My **router** is fine and works.
How do I include the functions from **controller** in my **server** file

I have:

- **server.js**

```js
var configure = require('./router');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// get an instance of router
var router = express.Router();
configure(router);

var request = require('request');
var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var rp = require('request-promise');

// Start the server
app.listen(port);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // support encoded bodies
console.log('Test server started! At http://localhost:' + port); // Confirms server start
//
// // START THE SERVER
// // ==============================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server has started!! ' + port);

// apply the routes to our application
app.use('/', router);
```

- **router.js**`

```js
  module.exports = function (router) {
    
            // route middleware that will happen on every request
            router.use(function (req, res, next) {
        
                // log each request to the console
                console.log(req.method, req.url);
        
                // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
                next();
            });
        
        // home page route (http://localhost:8080)
            router.get('/', function (req, res) {
                res.send('im the home page!');
            });
    
 

    router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
                res.send('this is the login form');
            })
    
            // process the form (POST http://localhost:8080/login)
            .post('/login', function (req, res) {
                console.log('processing'); // shows on console when post is made
                res.send('processing the login form!'); // output on postman
            });
    };
```

- **controller.js**

```js
    var password = 'gf.09';
    var userkey = 'dfgg';
    var emailAdmin = 'rt.r@rt.co.uk';
    
    // Start the server
    app.listen(port);
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // support encoded bodies
    console.log('Test server started! At http://localhost:' + port); // Confirms server start
    
    var firstFunction = function () {
        return new Promise (function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                app.post('/back-end/test', function (req, res) {
                    console.log(req.body);
                    var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                    res.send(login);
                    resolve({
                        data_login_email: login
                    });
                });
                console.error("First done");
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
    
    var secondFunction = function () {
        return new Promise (function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                    userKey: userkey,
                    email: emailAdmin,
                    password: password,
                    DEBUG: false
                }, function (err, client) {
                    if (err) {
                        // Authentication failed
                        console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                    } else {
                        // Authentication successful
                        var api_key = client.apiKey;
                        console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                        resolve({data_api: api_key});
                    }
                });
                console.error("Second done");
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
    
    
    function thirdFunction(result) {
        return new Promise (function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var headers = {
                    'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                };
    // Configure the request
                var api = result[1].data_api;
                var login_email = result[0].data_login_email;
                var options = {
                    url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: headers,
                    form: {
                        'email': login_email,
                        'user_key': userkey,
                        'api_key': api
                    },
                    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                };
    
    // Start the request
                rp(options)
                    .then(function (parsedBody) {
                        console.error(login_email, "Is a user, login pass!");
    
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.error("fail no such user");
                        // res.status(400).send()
    
                    });
                console.error("Third done");
            }, 3000);
        }
        );
    }
    
    // sequence of functions
    Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
        .then(thirdFunction);
```

**What I have tried**

```
var routers = require('./router');
var controller = require('./test');
// var controller = require('./test.js','./router' );
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var router = express.Router();

routers(router);
controller(Promise);
```

and

```
module.exports = function (Promise) {  

all functions 

}
```

Problem is some of the variables are not available to **controller.js** so i get errors such as  :

> app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {

```
            ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dead simple use same logic as you applied in your router.js.

Use something like below in controller.js:

```
exports.function_name = function(params, ...){
. . .
}
```

Then access these function by importing the controller.js

```
var controller = require('./controller.js');
controller.function_name(param..)   # execute with required params and callback
```

If you want to return an object then you can do module.exports

```
module.exports = Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction);
```

The controller object contain a promise now so

```
var controller = require('./controller.js');
```

controller object directly can be used as a promise no need to call a function now.

A better alternative is to export all the functions from controller.js and then in app.js you can use them with promise.

```
Promise.all([controller.firstFunction(), controller.secondFunction()]) .then(controller.thirdFunction);
```

Comment: I got you, I was trying this before but could not get to work. ill try again. thanks

Comment: if you can mention the error you experienced before then it would be great

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Ill try again if i get errors ill update answer if not ill accept your answer

Comment: See the edit if it still does not work then let me know

Comment: Excellent, Ill try this and let you know. If i use `module.exports = Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction);` would I then use `controller.(Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction))` ?

Comment: Or a better idea would be to export all the functions from controller then use promise in app.js . I will edit with alternative also

Comment: Sorry was away, got problem with just using `controller();` as i get a error controller not a function, ill try your updated answer and comment